# Solution explorer tab not able to display in VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, hide, show, solution-explorer

I am not able to see solution explorer tab in VS 2010 . I also have used command  Ctrl+w,s but sill not able to see . When i do Start Debugging (F5)than it get display but as i stop debugging i gets hide .

Comment: How about clicking `View - Solution Explorer`? Or `Ctrl + Alt + L`?

Comment: That sounds like it's out of screen... how about turning it on via View - Solution Explorer and then pressing Windows key + arrow left/right?

Comment: It Solved .I need to uninstalled Amazon web Service from control panel and its displaying. I am afraid .